# Why did Canonical reduce Ubuntu's (non-LTS) support time to 9 months?

Tags: release-management

Is reducing support time the first step to having a rolling distribution?
Is there any other purpose?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is reducing support time the first step of going to have a rolling distribution?

No. Well maybe. Who knows... but the current vote was 3-0 against a rolling release.

> Or there is any other purpose?

- Here is the [meeting summary](http://ubottu.com/meetingology/logs/ubuntu-meeting/2013/ubuntu-meeting.2013-03-18-21.01.moin.txt).
- Here is the [proposal](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2013-March/001527.html).

> In order to go even faster as the leading free software platform, meet
>   the needs of both our external users and internal communities (Unity,
>   Canonical, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and many many others) and prepare for a
>   wider role in personal computing, Ubuntu is considering:

> *2. Reducing the amount of release management, and duration of support,
>   for interim releases*.
>   Very few end users depend on 18 months support for interim releases. The
>   proposal is to reduce the support for interim releases to 7 months,
>   thereby providing constant support for those who stay on the latest
>   interim release, or any supported LTS releases. Our working assumption
>   is that the latest interim release is used by folks who will be
>   involved, even if tangentially, in the making of Ubuntu, and LTS
>   releases will be used by those who purely consume it.