# Lubuntu 19.04 lack of support

Tags: lubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I am using Lubuntu 19.04 and am very pleased with the speed and performance however support has now ceased for this iteration.
The question is should I go back to Lubuntu 18, as suggested, or switch to Ubuntu.
My PC is a virtually new  HP Pavilion with plenty of grunt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) and [Will ESM also become available for Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001714/)

Comment: Seeing as you are on 19.04 now, it makes more sense to  upgrade to 19.10.  To go back to 18.04 would probably consist of a reinstall, with a possibly loss of data if you don't have backups.  Can also upgrade to 20.04 from 19.10 and then stay on that.

Comment: Just update to whatever you are prompted to.  Next time you reinstall from scratch pick a LTS version.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/270529/why-did-canonical-reduce-ubuntus-non-lts-support-time-to-9-months states "Very few end users depend on 18 months support for interim releases. "  That is Canonical's official stance on the short life  of interim (i.e., non-LTS) releases,, from 2013.

Answer (score 12):

http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/

https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-19-04-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/

From the Lubuntu EOL message is

> **Lubuntu 19.04 End of Life and Current Support Statuses**
>
> Lubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) will reach End of Life on Thursday, January 23, 2020. This means that after that date there will be no further security updates or bugfixes released. We highly recommend that you update to 19.10 as soon as possible if you are still running 19.04.
>   After January 23rd, the only supported releases of Lubuntu will be
>   18.04, with LXDE, and 19.10, with LXQt. All other releases of Lubuntu will be considered unsupported, and will no longer receive any further
>   updates from the Lubuntu team.
>
> You can find instructions on how to upgrade your Lubuntu installation
>   here at our [manual page](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/D/upgrading.html).

You'll also note later in the reference, the reason I'd suggest not returning to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, ie.

> Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop
>   environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04
>   or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken
>   system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please
>   do a fresh install. The installation image can be obtained from our
>   downloads page.

I would strongly recommend the upgrade to 19.10, providing a path to move to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS currently in development.

Comment: fyi:  @K7AAY  I'm not adding this answer because there is anything wrong with your answer, I wanted to include the Lubuntu specific references/details

Comment: If you go back to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (*we're QA-testing the 18.04.4 ISO's currently; the i386 on the machine to my left is mid-install*), you'll have support until April-2021 (3 years from April-2018), where as the 19.10 will upgrade to 20.04 which has 3 years just for starters.. ie. a much longer support path without the hassle of re-installs...

Comment: As an unlikely aside; if your system was x86 (32-bit) which officially was never released, though ISOs were produced for x86 Lubuntu & Xubuntu for the first third of the release cycle, thus upgrades were generated & available. There is however no 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade possible. That was disabled a few days before 19.10's release.  In this circumstance I'd recommend re-installing a 18.04 system as its supported.

Answer (score 11):

Neither. You do not need to reinstall Lubuntu 18.04 or start over with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, because you can upgrade to Lubuntu 19.10, which is very easy, and **fully supported**.

This is a general solution for all users of Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, and other [supported Ubuntu flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours).

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade  
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

=

For reference only, if performing an upgrade from an LTS version (not the case here), also do

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

On the file's last line, change the value of *Prompt* from **lts** to **normal** .

Save the edit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm and exit with <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>.

=

Either way, continue with `do-release-upgrade` .

When it completes, reboot, and run `lsb_release -a` to confirm 19.10 is installed OK.

Comment: Why are the last 2 steps required? Wouldn't it be `normal` by default if the OP is already on 19.04 (19.04 was not an LTS release)?

Comment: You mean "at the last line of the file, change the value of Prompt from lts to normal ." and not the last two steps "When it completes, reboot, and run lsb_release -a to confirm 19.10 is installed OK." ? You are technically correct, but sooner or later someone here will use this for an LTS, so I am just belt-and-suspendering this.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant to say the last 2 commands regarding the installation of `update-manager-core` and editing the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file.